# Export Single Sheet to PDF in Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have many sheets in a Spreadsheet. I have 2 sheets that I would like to export every time. Sheet One is a sheet with the information. Sheet Two is the sheet I need to give to customers and it takes references from Sheet One.

Currently, I create a new temporary spreadsheet, copy Sheet One to the new spreadsheet, then copy Sheet Two to the temporary spreadsheet. After, I convert the temporary spreadsheet to a pdf. Then I delete the temporary spreadsheet and save the pdf into a folder in Google Drive.

The PDF created contains 2 pages of both sheets. I only need Sheet Two. If I only transfer Sheet Two, the sheet is left with many #REF errors since Sheet One isn't there. Is there any way to export only Sheet Two without have the #REF errors?

Here is my code below:

```
//create a temporary spreadsheet, copy both files onto it
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(nameOfSheet);
var d = ss.getSheetByName('Data').copyTo(newSpreadsheet); //the sheet     with all the information
d.setName('Data');

sheetToCopy.copyTo(newSpreadsheet); //the sheet that uses references from the data sheet
newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1")); //delete the original sheet of the new spreadsheet
var blobOfNewSpreadsheet = newSpreadsheet.getBlob(); //create pdf
folder.createFile(blobOfNewSpreadsheet); //add to folder


//delete the temporary spreadsheet2
var deleteSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
deleteSpreadsheet.setTrashed(true);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hidden sheets are not included when a spreadsheet is exported via getBlob. So you can temporarily hide any unwanted sheets prior to exporting.

```
function export() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unwanted Sheet');
  sheet.hideSheet();
  DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  sheet.showSheet();
}
```

The above only hides one sheet, which is enough in the context of your question. Here is a version that hides everything but one.

```
function exportSheet(sheetName) {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }
  DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! The one I thought of was copying the display values of the sheet I wanted instead of the references for each cell. This solution is much faster.

Comment: Please note that this saves the spreadsheet in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same query and now I have tried many solutions but the following code is the best one as per my knowing. This script does not create a temporary sheet and is a bit faster than the old method.


Forgive me if I am wrong but just sharing it for everyone's benefit.

```js
function generatePdf() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets(); // Get active sheet.
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var pdfName = sheetName + ".pdf"; // Set the output filename as SheetName.
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents(); // Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  var theBlob = createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() || 'admin@gmail.com';
  var custemail = sourceSheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  email = email + "," + custemail;
  // Subject of email message
  const subject = `Your subject Attachement: ${sheetName}`;
  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your image
  const body = "body";
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [theBlob]
    });
  // delete pdf if already exists
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  sourceSpreadsheet.toast("Emailed to " + email, "Success");

}

function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +    '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    +    '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +    '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    +    '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +    '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +    '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    +    '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    +    '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  // request export url
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  return theBlob;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I've been pursuing similar, but have not been able to find documentation of all the query parameters. Can you please point me to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Top solution didn't work for me. Broken references, even with the "fix" in there.

The following did though.

It's a bit more elegant because it "hides" the sheets you don't need. Contrary to the top-rated solution which duplicates a spreadsheet, deleting sheets, and then downloading it.

```
function exportSheet() { 
  var sheetName = "YOUR SHEET NAME HERE";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR SPREADSHEET ID HERE");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
  newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID")); 
  //I just did this to move the file to somewhere else. 
}
```