# Export to PDF only 1 sheet of the whole spreadsheet in PHP client

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I have a web app that calculates quotations for building houses using a Google Sheet. Once the client completes a form with the inputs, I calculate the cost and generate a spreadsheet with the corresponding values to send to the client via email.

How can I export only the corresponding sheet to PDF, and not all the other that are useful for us (but not for the client).

I am using Google's PHP API client, both the Sheets API and the Drive API, and there is no method to export just one sheet: `drive.files.export` method exports the whole spreadsheet.

If I try using the `spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo` method, I can copy the corresponding sheet to a new spreadsheet, but since the values of this sheet are calculated by formulas with dependencies on the rest of the sheet, I get cell value errors in the newly created spreadsheet.

I don't know if I can grant access to the new spreadsheet to another spreadsheet grammatically.

Anyone knows a workaround to export a single sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Single Sheet to PDF in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197358/generate-pdf-of-only-one-sheet-of-my-spreadsheet

Comment: It is quite similar, but I am generating everything from my php server, so I use the php client library. Everytime a user sends the form, I make a copy of my spreadsheet template and fulfull the users inputs. There are 8 different sheets in the spreadseet, each one calculating values from the other sheets starting with the user inputs. After the data is fulfilled I have to export just 1 of the sheets to PDF to send it via email. All this from my apache server which is receiving the http form.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Export Single Sheet to PDF in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script), have you tried adjusting sheet visibility? In Sheets REST API, you can do this with an [Update Sheet Properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest) request. You can bundle several of these into a batch request, to ensure all but the desired sheet is hidden prior to conversion.

In REST, this looks like:

```
{
  "requests": [
    "updateSheetProperties" {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": ...
        "hidden": true,
      }
    "fields": "hidden"
    },
    "updateSheetProperties" {
      ...
  ],
  "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": false
}
```

In the PHP client, you'd use the [batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.html) method and [this request](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this first thing tomorrow morning, it looks promising!...:)

Comment: I am trying the following code:

    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    $requests = array();
    foreach ($sheetIds as $sId)  {

        $request= new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest();
        $request_prop = new Google_Service_Sheets_SheetProperties();
        $request_prop->setSheetId($sId);
        $request_prop->setHidden(true);
        $request->setProperties($request_prop);
        $requests[] = $request;
    }
    $body->setRequests($requests);
    $response = $sheet_service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spId, $body);

Comment: And I keep getting this error: 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"properties\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"properties\" at 'requests[1]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received...

Comment: By the way, what is the correct way to post this info? I dont feel I am doing it correctly....:)

Comment: @ÁngelBlanco It looks like you're doing it correctly, so I'm not sure why it's failing. (I don't actually use the PHP client, so I can't clarify the correct sequence.) Could possibly be worthy of its own question (and in that question the code format will actually be possible too!)

Comment: I already did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373536/hide-sheets-with-google-php-spreadsheets-client