# Error when writing into a google spreadsheet using google spreadsheet api(javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I was trying to implement the Google Sheets API in js, and the read function works fine but while attempting to write something in the spreadsheet, I get the following error. 
Here is the snippet:-

[image: Error]

PS: this is my first question on stack overflow so try to ignore any mistakes

```
 var values = [
     [
       "CO16338","CO16331","CO16330" ],
   ];
   var body = {
     values: values
   };
   gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId:'1k1s95YiuWMjeOCMmpj8DQaj705ZC6Uq4UC7pEEU0zko',
      range:'!G1:G5',
      valueInputOption:"RAW",
      resource: body
   }).then((response) => {
     var result = response.result;
     console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells updated.`);
   });
```

The error, in detail:

```
{  "error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOption\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'valueInputOption' could not be found in request message.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOption\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'valueInputOption' could not be found in request message."
      }
    ]
  }
]}}
```

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382301/error-while-writing-into-a-google-spreadsheet-using-google-api and similar issue as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373536/hide-sheets-with-google-php-spreadsheets-client

Comment: Did you try removing the `valueInputOption` parameter from your request?

Comment: @HugoSilva OP essentially copies the example from the REST documentation for [`spreadsheets.values.update()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update#examples).  @OP: does your JS api client have the ability to modify the request? If you view the `Java` example, they use `request.setValueInputOption()` rather than directly build it in the request.

Comment: Is the `client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append` correct?  Everything I've ever used is just `client.spreadsheets.*`.  Just wondering b/c request body looks fine.