# Error while 'writing' into a google spreadsheet using Google API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

#### Code used

```
  var values = [
    [
      'value1','value2','value3'
    ]
  ];
   var body = {
    values: values
  };
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: '1Lofhq9R7X5wzGvO7fMViN8D8q1W3fiNxO5jjP7XL_s0',
    range: 'Sheet1!A1:A4',
    valueInputOption:'RAW',
    resource: body
  }).then((response) => {
    var result = response.result;
    console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells updated.`);
  });
```

Error shown

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOption\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'valueInputOption' could not be found in request message.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
            "fieldViolations": [
              {
                "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOption\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'valueInputOption' could not be found in request message."
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I've changed access settings of the google spreadsheet to allow anyone with it's link to view and edit it. This error is arising only when I'm trying to write into the spreadsheet, I'm able to read a spreadsheet using other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had specified the authorization scope required by the API incorrectly(before the update function was called).
Error got fixed after using
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` 
instead of 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`

Answer (score 2):

No one knows what domains you white-listed so no one can reproduce your code. And your spreadsheet doesn't have the `Class Data` sheet and you tried wrongly to write at `A1:C1` not `A1:A4`.

So I added a sheet and changed `values` and tried with the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update). The result was `200 OK`. Maybe you can try `'RAW'` instead of `"RAW"` or/and `values: values` instead of `resource: body`.

[image]

Comment: I've changed 'Class Data' to 'Sheet1' (even though it didn't cause any trouble in the 'get' function).I've tried using 'RAW' instead of "RAW" without any change in error.I've also changed 'A1:C1' to 'A1:A4' (It isnt the reason for the error though,it could have left remaining cells empty).Other than that, we are supposed to assign 'resource' an object containing the values that we want to insert,right?So, what am I exactly supposed to use instead of ` 'resource: body' `?

Comment: As I said, just replace ````resource: body```` to ````values: values```` in your current code. Have you tried that?