# Sharing a google sheet via Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-editor

I am looking to share a google sheet via email in the script.  This code correctly creates an email draft, and inserts a hyperlink to my sheet.  I would rather have it look like it does when you insert it as a drive link in GMAIL.

[Here is a sample of what it looks like when you insert as a drive link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xowL.png)

**Code**:

```
function getSheetId() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId().toString();
};
function getSheetUrl() {
   var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
   var url = '';
   url += SS.getUrl();
   url += '#gid=';
   url += ss.getSheetId(); 
   return url;
  }

 function notDumb(){
   var body = getSheetUrl();
   var options = {}
   options.htmlBody ='<a href=\"' +body+ '">Here is the File</a>';
   GmailApp.createDraft("john@john.com", "Testing",'', options); 

 }
```

Comment: Send it as plain body(without html)

Comment: You could also save the sheet as PDF [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338531/7215091](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338531/7215091);