# generate/making a grahic for each student in googlesheet and auto save the graphic image to gdrive

Tags: google-sheets, graphics

need your help again..

so I have many student. and every week we have exam.

so I want to make individual Graphic of their progress for every week.. and send it ass attachment with autocrat to their email.

my problem is

1. how do I make an individual graphic continuedly (i mean not one by one change the name)
2. how to save that individual graphic to google drive
3. how to get the link image on google drive

those 3 problem is to make report for my student one by one like this pic

[image: like this pic]

please share idea with me.. I'm really thank you for helping me here..
here the spreadsheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmS7PM65CMGGe5g00ojqqiK2CFr5HFgo_6L_Qki7QLw/edit#gid=1364826426

Comment: The added image is so small that the values are unreadable. Anyway, please provide and specific the data. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I have created three charts in the spreadsheet for you.

[Save or publish your chart](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047436?hl=en)

[image]

Comment: cool thx for helping me out.. but I need to make a report pdf for my student one by one each name.. like in picture that i post in my sheet..

Comment: the diagram3 is better one.. i can chose it.. but how can i show the x line name? like in sheet graphic??

Comment: It seems you have deleted the series from the chat. You should select with the slicer. The names were shown in the legend.

Comment: beg you pardon.. i dont get it what you mean

Comment: I cannot get what is you desired diagram because diagram3 has been changed after I created it.

Comment: im really sorry.. so how to fix it??

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand and solve your problem all, since your problem seems a bit too complex.
However, I know how to save a sheet as a PDF easier and get the PDF's URL automatically.
It needs a script program.
I made a sample program based on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338531/14952561).

This is my code.

```js
function exportPDF(){
  // get parameters
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var fileName = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  sheet.getRange("B4").setValue("");

  // export the sheet
  var fileUrl = exportSheet(sheetName, fileName);
  // show the url
  sheet.getRange("B4").setValue(fileUrl);
}

// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script
function exportSheet(sheetName, fileName) {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var fileUrl = "";
  try{
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
        sheets[i].hideSheet()
      }
    }
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
    file.setName(fileName);
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    fileUrl = file.getUrl();
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
  finally{
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      sheets[i].showSheet()
    }
  }
  return fileUrl;
}
```

If this can help, check this sample sheet and make a copy. ([File]-[Make a copy])
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lCxNSaXsd9tno4xdog6Usa0l1SZeuXrc62Oi6TK-VsY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: hahahaha yes its to complex reallly.. and im really hard to explain problem..

Comment: for making pdf I all ready use autocrat.. that very good tools really.. but the problem is.. want give a diagram to each student.. and that what autocrat cannot do.. so i want to make like email merge excel to word.. which every change the table the diagram will change too.. and that i cant find in every where..

Comment: i use google form and when student input their name.. autocrat will generate a pdf of their personal score but I failed to show their diagram

Comment: I see what you want to do. I didn't know the `autocrat`, and I looked up the outline. I agree It's a good tool but seems it only support text data. I believe you should make a program via Google Apps Script and it's going to be a little hard work...