# Saving a specific sheet from the workbook as a PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 3 sheets in my workbook and I want to save a specific sheet as a PDF to a specific folder in my Google Drive. I have this code below. However, it is saving the entire workbook as PDF and not that specific sheet.

```
function checkSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tracking");
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  if(sh.getRange("C6").getValue() == "Yes") {
    var theBlob = ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName("mypdf");
    fldr.createFile(theBlob);
  }
}
```

Tracking - is the sheet that I want to save as PDF
folder id - is the id taken from the url of the folder where I want to save the PDF file

I tried looking for different syntax for getBlob and I am not able to get that specific sheet saved as a PDF. Here are is a link that I referenced.

[Export Single Sheet to PDF in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that [your referenced thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script) will be useful. But, from your question, I couldn't understand your tested script. So, in this case, I would like to introduce the modified script using your referenced thread.

#### Modified script:

```js
function checkSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tracking");
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  if (sh.getRange("C6").getValue() == "Yes") {

    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to export as PDF format.
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
        sheets[i].hideSheet();
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might not be required to be used.
    var theBlob = ss.getBlob().setName("mypdf");
    fldr.createFile(theBlob);
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }

  }
}
```

- When this script is run, only "Sheet1" is included in the exported PDF file.
- By the way, in this case, when the blob is retrieved from Spreadsheet, the Spreadsheet is automatically converted to PDF format. So, in this case, `var theBlob = ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName("mypdf");` can be replaced with `var theBlob = ss.getBlob().setName("mypdf");`.

#### Note:

- As another approach, in this case, when the endpoint for exporting the Spreadsheet as PDF format is used, the modified script is as follows.

  ```js
  function checkSheet() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tracking");
    var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
    if (sh.getRange("C6").getValue() == "Yes") {

      const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to export as PDF format.
      const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()}`;
      const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
      fldr.createFile(blob.setName("mypdf"));

    }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Shan Jose In this case, if the sheet name, which is not included in the active spreadsheet, is set to `sheetName`, an error occurs for both scripts. Please be careful about this.

Comment: | Thanks a tone. The second approach worked just fine. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have run into a 'Returned code 500' error with the script. It worked once and then it started giving me this error. I have raised another question as I did not not how to follow up on this question. The link to the new question is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388063/converting-a-specific-sheet-in-a-workbook-to-a-pdf