# Error message "TypeError: spreadSheetSub.getAs is not a function" while trying to download a google Sheet (Google App Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a complete newbie to Google App Scripts and i need help making some code work. I'm trying to get the system store it as a PDF into my drive immediatel upon being run. I get the output that ".getAs is not a function" that the spreadSheetSub can use

```
function savePDF() {
  var sheetName = "PDF_Sheet";
  var spreadSheetMain = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadSheetSub = spreadSheetMain.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (spreadSheetSub){
    var pdfBlob = spreadSheetSub.getAs('application/pdf');

    var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("PDF_Admission_Saves").createFile(pdfBlob);
    pdfFile.setName("test.pdf");
  }

}
```

Comment: In your script, `spreadSheetSub` is Class Sheet. Unfortunately, Class Sheet has no method of `getAs`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) I think that this is the reason for your current issue. About exporting a specific sheet from Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script, I thought that these threads might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49197358 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38335143

Comment: I've made changes to the code by hiding the sheet I don't want exported, but now am getting another error message "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp."

Comment: May I respectfully suggest that it might be more efficient if you search on stackoverflow.com (or the more widely on the internet) for questions dealing with printing a sheet as PDF. You will find many resolved precedents.

Answer (score 0):

**`var pdfBlob = spreadSheetSub.getAs('application/pdf');`**

The error is caused because a "sheet" variable (`spreadSheetSub`) has been used with a "spreadsheet" method (`getAs`).

- `spreadSheetSub` is a reference to a specific sheet -> "PDF_Sheet".
- OTOH, `getAs(contentType)` is a "spreadsheet" method [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getascontenttype).

  - There is not equivalent "sheet" method.

---

**`var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("PDF_Admission_Saves")`**

- `getFolderById` expects "The ID of the folder". Though this *is* a string, it is not the "name" of the folder, it is the folder's ID.

---

FWIW, to manually find the ID of a folder, try this explanation from [azuqua.com](https://learn.azuqua.com/connector-reference/googledrive/#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20folder%20in,ID%20would%20be%20%E2%80%9C1dyUEebJaFnWa3Z4n0BFMVAXQ7mfUH11g%E2%80%9D.)

- Navigate to the folder in Google Drive.
- Copy the Folder ID found in the URL. This is everything that comes after “folder/” in the URL.

  - For example, if the URL was “https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dyUEebJaFnWa3Z4n0BFMVAXQ7mfUH11g”,
  - then the Folder ID would be “1dyUEebJaFnWa3Z4n0BFMVAXQ7mfUH11g”.